# Alter weather block behaviour?

Tags: blocks

In the [weather](https://www.drupal.org/project/weather) module, if a user has not configured a custom weather block, the block does not display:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_block_view().
 */
function weather_block_view($delta = '') {
  global $user;
  module_load_include('inc', 'weather', 'weather.common');
  $block = array();
  // Handle the 'system_NUMBER' type of blocks
  if (strpos($delta, '_') === FALSE) {
    $display_type = $delta;
  }
  else {
    list($display_type, $display_number) = explode('_', $delta);
  }
  $forecast_days = (int) variable_get('weather_forecast_days', '2');
  switch ($display_type) {
    case 'user':
      if (weather_access_userblock()) {
        // Show the user's custom weather block, if there is already
        // a place configured. Otherwise, do not show the block.
        $places = weather_get_places_in_use('user', $user->uid);
        if (!$places) {
          return;
        }
        ...
        [from weather.module]
```

Is there a way of displaying a 'Please set your weather location' link, instead of nothing at all, without applying a patch to the module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7) in your custom module to display text if user has not configured the custom location.you can access the current user object from global $user if you want to perform any operation on it.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter().
 */
function demo_wipe_block_view_weather_user_alter(&$data, $block) {
//Check here that whether user has configured or not. 
  if(!is_array($data)) {
    $data['subject'] = t('Blah Blah Blah!');
    $data['content'] = t('Blah Blah Blah! link');
  }
}
```

P.S. : I have tested it on php 5.5.3

I think you should also specify this as a feature request in the module issue queue to set default whether location(that should be in admin configuration) on user whether block if user has not configured the block yet.

Comment: I have created a contrib module for setting the empty text per block.https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/naveenvalecha/2377891 would love to see the reviews from you.

Comment: Finally Contrib module block_noresults is out for this.Use the contrib module for the no results behaviour https://www.drupal.org/project/block_noresults

Answer (score 0):

You could just create your own wrapping block. Implement hook_block_view, and call `weather_block_view` from it.

If you get back a useful response, simply return it as your own blocks output. If you don't, return your own output instead, by generating the appropriate link with `l`.

Answer (score -2):

1. Enable PHP Filter module.
2. Create custom block, add on textarea "Please set your weather location" link , set title to "Weather".
3. Set PHP visibility for block next code:

   `global $user;
   $places = weather_get_places_in_use('user', $user->uid);
   return !$places;`
4. Move block position to under Weather block.
5. So when user doesn't set Weather, he will see set location link block, otherwise, he will see Weather block. No hacks :)

Comment: I _strongly_ object to the recommendation to use the PHP-module, especially when it's done without a big disclaimer that it's a huge security problem and should be avoided. -1

Comment: I strongly suggest to not use PHP-module on any drupal site and I never used PHP filter on my any drupal site.